# trying to Serialize parents member variables from child where parent does not implement Serializable

Tags: java, inheritance, serialization

I am aware that you cannot serialize parent's member variables if parent does not implement Serializable interface.

I have created a sample program and trying to find a way (no matter how hacky it is) to serialize parent classe's member variables without changing it to implement serializable.

below is the code :

```
class s
{ 
    int i;
    public int getI() {
        return i;
    }
    public void setI(int i) {
        this.i = i;
    }
    public int getJ() {
        return j;
    }
    public void setJ(int j) {
        this.j = j;
    }
    int j;
    private int fun(){
         return 1;
     }
}

class m extends s implements Serializable
{
    int k;
    int l;
    public int getK() {
        return k;
    }
    public void setK(int k) {
        this.k = k;
    }
    public int getL() {
        return l;
    }
    public void setL(int l) {
        this.l = l;
    }

    public int fun(){
        return 2;
    }
}

class n1{
    public static void main(String...s)
    {
        m m1  = new m();
        m1.setI(100);
        m1.setJ(101);
        m1.setK(401);
        m1.setL(701);

        try {
            OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(new File("d:/aaa.data"));
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(os);
            oos.writeObject(m1);
            InputStream is = new FileInputStream(new File("d:/aaa.data"));
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(is);
            m m2 = (m)ois.readObject();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }       
    }
}
```

I would appreciate your thoughts on this matter with upvote for sure :) 
thanks

Comment: how about using a proxy for parent class

Comment: @Ramanlfc  could you elaborate more?

Comment: Serialized files are binary and should not be stored with the `.txt` extension.

Comment: @EJP: edited the code as per your suggestion.thanks.

Comment: read this : https://dzone.com/articles/serialization-proxy-pattern

Comment: @Ramanlfc: Beauiful !! thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question.

Thanks to @Ramanlfc came to know Serialization Proxy Pattern.

Serialization Proxy Pattern comes handy for conditions exactly like this;

here is the code that implements Serialization Proxy pattern in above code.

```
class m extends s implements Serializable {
    int k;
    int l;

    public m() {
    }

    public m(int i, int j, int k, int l) {
        this.i = i;
        this.j = j;
        this.k = k;
        this.l = l;
    }

    private static class MProxy implements Serializable {

        int i;
        int j;
        int k;
        int l;

        public MProxy(m point) {
            this.i = point.getI();
            this.j = point.getJ();
            this.k = point.getK();
            this.l = point.getL();
        }

        private Object readResolve() {
            return new m(i, j, k, l);
        }

    }

    private Object writeReplace() {
        return new MProxy(this);
    }

    public int getK() {
        return k;
    }

    public void setK(int k) {
        this.k = k;
    }

    public int getL() {
        return l;
    }

    public void setL(int l) {
        this.l = l;
    }

    public int fun() {
        return 2;
    }
}
```

to implement this pattern I added a new  class `MProxy`. which is a kind of container that contains copy of state of child class.

and wrote a method `writeReplace()` to override default serialization writeobject behaviour. It now return instance of `MProxy` instead of `this` which is then written to the file.

here no changes were made to parent class.

Comment: A static nested class is not an inner class.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this by adding the following methods to the child class:

1. A `writeObject()` method that also serializes the members of the non-serializable class.
2. A `readObject()` method that deserializes them.

The required signatures of these methods and what they can/must do are defined in the [Object Serialization Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/platform/serialization/spec/serialTOC.html).